# Why I am not able to switch to third window opened by Selenium WebDriver? I can switch to second window and perform steps but not third

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iterator, set

Below is my code:

//this click opens second window. page is page object reference and method is written to click on a button

```
public enterDetails(String fname)
{
firstPage.clickAddAdditionalDetail();
String parentWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
String childWin1="";
String childWin2="";
Set<String> windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator=windows.iterator();
childWin1=iterator.next();
driver.switchTo.window(childWin1);
firstPage.clickOneTimeDetail();// able to click this on second window, this click opens third window
Thread.sleep(3000);
childWin1=driver.getWindowHandle();
windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
childWin2=iterator.next();
driver.switchTo.window(childWin2);
// the third window is opened but driver control is not getting passed i think. even when i print all window ids it is printing same id for all parent and child
addDetailPage.enterFirstName(String fname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

**Problem one:**

**Iterator of a set even if its a hashset its not ordered. iterator.next() returns element from the iterator object randomly till the iterator size becomes zero**. So it should not be used for switch window logic as you won't always get the element you want.

use it only if you want to iterate through all windows  in any order.

**Problem two**

After each element output iterator removes the element from memory and decrements the iterator size.

so if you have a set of size 1, and you try to call iterator.next() two times it will throw element not found as after first next() size is 0. and for second next() you are trying to get element from a iterator of size zero as the size gets decremented

**in your code**

You are literally doing the below logic.

```
Set < String > hash_Set = new HashSet < String > ();

hash_Set.add("Geeks");


Iterator a = hash_Set.iterator();

System.out.println(a.next());

hash_Set
    = new HashSet < String > ();

hash_Set.add("1");
hash_Set.add("2");


System.out.println(a.next());
```

If you run this code you will get an error saying there is no such element for the second a.next().

This is because the hash_set had only one element when you created the iterator.This create a iterator of size 1 . On first .next() it removes one element and makes size to zero.

Even after updating the hash_set to two elements, **iterator is not reinitialised.** so when you call a.next() it is trying to find somethign from a iterator of size '0'.

**Soulution**

use:

```
    Set<String> handlesSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Object[] handles = handlesSet.toArray();        
    childWin1=handles[handles.length-1];
```

Also make sure you call :

```
    handlesSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
    handles = handlesSet.toArray();     
    childWin2=handles[handles.length-1];
```

each time a new window is opened so that you reinitialize the array.